# Which tables are updated in data migration tool Map step

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, migration, data-migration-tool

In Magento data migration tool, we have a map step which migrates catalog and sales data. As I only want to migrate sales data, I need to ignore the unwanted tables in map.xml that are related to catalog and other data. I need the list of tables that are affected in map step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Map step` is responsible for transferring most of data from Magento 1 to Magento 2. This step reads instructions from `map.xml` file (located in etc dir). The file describes differences between data structures of source (Magento 1) and destination (Magento 2). In case Magento 1 contains tables or fields that belong to some extension that does not exist in Magento 2, then these entities can be placed here to ignore them by Map Step. Otherwise it will show an error message.

This step transfers all attributes (e.g. product, customer, RMA) from Magento 1 to Magento 2. It uses `map-eav.xml` file that contains rules similar to the ones in `map.xml` file for specific cases of processing data.

Some of the tables that are processed in the step:

- eav_attribute
- eav_attribute_group
- eav_attribute_set
- eav_entity_attribute
- catalog_eav_attribute
- customer_eav_attribute
- eav_entity_type

In addition to the Map Step, there are other steps in the config.xml file which migrate data with major format and structure changes, including:

- Url Rewrite Step
- OrderGrids Step
- EAV Step

**Unlike the Map Step, these steps scan a predefined list of tables instead of all tables.**

Reference: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/migration-tool-internal-spec.html

**I hope this will help**

Comment: The tables mentioned are related to EAV step. I need the exact list of tables that come under the Map step.

Comment: @SufyanKhot I added more detail in the answer. Map step does not have predefined list of tables, it includes `all database tables` that's why I share EAV mapping tables. In order to support my claim please check this reference https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/extend-the-tool.html. If my answers helps you please mark my answer correct and upvote my answer. keep coding :) thanks